# frozen while booting on a screen that reads [ 107.643618] nouveau 000:5a:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 01000000 [] ch 0 [00f8ff000 DRM]. How to fix?

Tags: boot, nouveau

This happens on my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop frequently. Probably twice a week. I want it to stop.

It freezes while booting, or prints wild strings of jibberish. The text reads like what there is in the title. Sometimes it updates the number on the left ~100x/sec. The string in full reads like:

[ 107.643618] nouveau 000:5a:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 01000000 [] ch 0 [00f8ff000 DRM] subc 0 mthd 0008 data 0000000

Just lines like that over and over. It’s now unfrozen and counting up to around 1905.xyzabc

I just want to use my computer… Ubuntu would be really impressive if not for this singular bug.

What do I do to make it never reappear? Or at least go away for years

Update, after printing jibberish lines for another few minutes, it turned itself off. Booted normally next time.

I always turn my Ubuntu laptop off using the shutdown in the UI.

edit: Here's a link to what the screen looks like. https://i.stack.imgur.com/62ynq.jpg

Comment: 1. Disable Secure Boot in UEFI 2. Install the recommended Nvidia drivers (in Software & Updates > Additional drivers). 3. Optional but strongly recommended: Update UEFI.

Comment: How did you like... how did you know?

Comment: Such `nouveau` errors typically occur with recent Nvidia graphics models without the Nvidia proprietary drivers. The open-source community driver doesn't support correctly many new and newish models.

Comment: update your graphics adapter. that worked for me...