# Ubuntu 22 freezes, syslog spammed with Nouveau entries

Tags: drivers, 22.04, freeze, nouveau

Was on a Zoom call with the screen shared, and everything suddenly freezes. Audio worked for a bit afterwards, but eventually stopped working as well. Taking a look at the system log after a hard reboot, I noticed that it was spammed with the following lines at the time when things started freezing. There are over 2 million of these lines in the log file, all logged within the span of 2 minutes.

```
Oct 17 11:37:00 kernel: [15845.633473] nouveau 0000:0e:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 00040000 [PBENTRY] ch 10 [017ef40000 Xwayland[2393]] subc 0 mthd 0000 data 00000000

Oct 17 11:37:00 kernel: [15845.633513] nouveau 0000:0e:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 00040000 [PBENTRY] ch 10 [017ef40000 Xwayland[2393]] subc 0 mthd 0000 data 00000000

Oct 17 11:37:00 kernel: [15845.633553] nouveau 0000:0e:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 00040000 [PBENTRY] ch 10 [017ef40000 Xwayland[2393]] subc 0 mthd 0000 data 00000000

Oct 17 11:37:00 kernel: [15845.633574] nouveau 0000:0e:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 00040000 [PBENTRY] ch 10 [017ef40000 Xwayland[2393]] subc 0 mthd 0000 data 00000000
```

Comment: It seems you have Nvidia graphics so perhaps you should be using Nvidia drivers instead of the community open-source `nouveau`. And unless you're dual-booting with Windows 11 you can easily disable Secure Boot in UEFI. Otherwise, besides installing the drivers you also need to use MOKutil to manually sign them for Secure Boot.

Comment: Please be precise with details; Ubuntu has products that use the *year* format (22) and others using the *year.month* format (eg. 22.04).  22 & 22.04 are different products; 22 is a server only system for *headless* operation so nouveau issues which imply screen make little sense.

Comment: Probably related/duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420777/frozen-while-booting-on-a-screen-that-reads-107-643618-nouveau-0005a00-0-f

Comment: originally I had the nvidia 515 driver, but the other day one of my monitors stopped working, so I switched to nouveau. It seems to work fine, except for that instance where things froze. I will try disabling uefi and switching back to the nvidia driver if the freezing happens again.